# Create matrix of random integers in Python with a desired step size

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, random, range

Need to write a Python script that creates a matrix of random integers based on 5 parameters:

1. Number of rows
2. Number of columns
3. Lowest value in random value range
4. Highest value in random value range
5. The step values in the range (ex: low=50, high=100, step=5... available random values include 50, 55, 60, 65... etc)

The function random.random_integers has not been working to give a step option.  I can't seem to put it together with the range function.

Here is an example:

This:
Size 3x4, range 22-37, step 2

Creates this:

```
[[26 22 32 28]  
 [24 30 26 22]  
 [36 34 22 36]]
```

Comment: What do you mean by step?

Answer (score 3):

Use randrange

```
import random
rows = 3
columns = 4
[[random.randrange(22, 37, 2) for x in range(columns)] for y in range(rows)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Or you could use numpy.

```
import numpy as np

rows  = 3
cols = 4
low = 22
high = 37
step = 2

matrix = np.random.choice([x for x in xrange(low,high,step)],rows*cols)
matrix.resize(rows,cols)

print(matrix)

>>> [[36 22 26 30]
     [22 26 36 34]
     [30 32 28 36]]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternate way without step.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> rows = 3
>>> cols = 4
>>> a = np.matrix(np.random.randint(22,37, size=(rows, cols)))
>>>
>>> a
matrix([[33, 25, 35, 32],
        [31, 23, 32, 35],
        [23, 25, 32, 34]])
>>>
```